# How to edit comments form on posts?

Tags: comment-form

I have an old theme installed

There's **a text under the text area for comments** I would like to edit/delete

Already tried in *settings-->discussions* and *comments.php* to find that text

Looked also between plugin.

Where could I watch at now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your theme, if it uses template, create a child theme and edit it. If it's not a part of comment template, edit another part.

You can try to find correct place with PsPad, Visual Code Studio or whatever else code editor while typing the phrase and searching in the template/plugin files.

If you need to hide it, use CSS (add `display:none`).

Comment: not found a child theme under the theme

Comment: Create one ;) You can use a plugin, for example [Child theme configurator](https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/)

Comment: downloaded all files, tried to find the string with Dreamweaver. Not found it :-(

Comment: Weird. Try to type onle part of the string, not whole and only in English (if you have it localized). It should be somewhere, or it's part of the WP default template (in that case, you will find it in wp-includes directory)